# WebRTC Coturn, not able to view remote user on some networks

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

I made a WebRTC video calling application that works and is able to share Audio and Video to the remote users and it also works on different networks.

We setup Coturn Server on Amazon EC2 Instance for NAT Traversal.
The issue that I'm facing is that on some networks (Globally), I'm not able to get the remote user's audio/video and I can't figure out what the issue is.

Trickle ICE test works perfectly. It's just some networks that are giving issues.

Also tried deploying Coturn on a separate EC2 instance.
tried to change ports to every possible turn configuration.

If anyone can shed some light on this one, please do let us know.

I'm attaching the logs

```
ICE(PC:1601497557091097 (id=10737418241 url=https://*****)): relay only option is set without any TURN server configured
ICE(PC:1601497557091097 (id=10737418241 url=https://*****)): relay only option results in no host candidate for IP4:192.168.43.57:0/UDP
ICE(PC:1601497557091097 (id=10737418241 url=https://*****)): relay only option is set without any TURN server configured
ICE(PC:1601497557091097 (id=10737418241 url=https://*****)): relay/proxy only option results in ICE TCP being disabled
ICE(PC:1601497557091097 (id=10737418241 url=https://*****)): couldn’t create any valid candidates



2:03
________
2:03
builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3
ICE(PC:1601487818957513 (id=4294967297 url=https://*****)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3
/builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3
ICE(PC:1601487818957513 (id=4294967297 url=https://*****)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3
ICE(PC:1601487818957513 (id=4294967297 url=https://*****): All candidates initialized
2:06
_________________________
2:06
ICE(PC:1601497557091097 (id=10737418241 url=https://*****)): relay only option results in no host candidate for IP6:[2401:4900:1202:b867:213f:764b:4942:4757]:0/UDP
```